# Saving text from a textbox to nsstring and then back to textbox

Tags: iphone, objective-c, textbox, nsstring, chat

i am creating a chat app for iphone. The chat between the phones work fine but i want to keep a transcript of the chat. So i created an NSstring and every time the user exits the chat to go to the main menu, the text from the text box is stored in the nsstring. When the the user goes back into the chat I want the string to be loaded into the text box. But when I tried this it does not work instead it crashes. The transcript is saved in the nsstring but cannot be loaded back into the text box. If it helps the error I get is: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Any help or other way to save the transcript is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: once check that textbox object is available or not while the use come back from other view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like one of your variables is not being retained properly, possibly the NSString. If you do it like this

```
NSString* str = textBox.text;
```

You'll have a pointer to the textBox's string, but the string will be released as soon as the textBox is dealloced. If you want to hang on to the string, use

```
NSString* str = [textBox.text copy];
```

Comment: Thanks NSString* str = [textBox.text copy]; worked like a charm :-)